# Fixing the error "No exports were found that match the constraint"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My windows 8 OS grabbed update and prompted me to update which I did but afterwards, my VS 2013 refused to open up any VS file showing the error message
"**No exports were found that match the constraint**"

Answer (score 2):

In fixing it, locate the path 
"C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0" and rename the folder "**ComponentModelCache**". This solves the VS issue.

[image]